# I need help getting my calculator to work- NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, calculator

I am trying to create a retail calculator that will will show sales prices of items. A user enters the original price of the item in a text box, and the percentage discounted in another box. The user then clicks the calculate button to get the answer. My problem is that I can not get the program to calculate the answer, instead I am getting a lot of error messages. I only see errors on a few of the lines, but I cannot figure out how to fix them. Below is the codes I have:

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * 
 * @author Owner
 */
public class RetailCalcForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private void close() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private static class number {

        public number() {
        }
    }

    private static class number2 {

        public number2() {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form RetailCalcForm
     */
    public RetailCalcForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        itemNameText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        originalPriceText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        percentDiscountedText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        calculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        salesPriceLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JComboBox departmentBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Item Name");

        jLabel2.setText("Original Price");

        jLabel3.setText("% Discounted");

        calculateButton.setText("Calculate Discount Price");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                calculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        salesPriceLabel.setText("Discounted Sales Price: ");

        exitButton.setText("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        departmentBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(
                new String[] { "Electronics", "Toys", "Clothing", "Housewares",
                        "Garden" }));
        departmentBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                departmentBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("Select Department");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
                getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(28, 28, 2Cool

                                .addGroup(
                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addGroup(
                                                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        jLabel2)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        jLabel1))
                                                                .addContainerGap())
                                                .addGroup(
                                                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                        salesPriceLabel,
                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                        310,
                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                                                        jLabel3)
                                                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                                                        jLabel4))
                                                                                                .addGap(26,
                                                                                                        26,
                                                                                                        26)
                                                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                                                        percentDiscountedText,
                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                                                        145,
                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                                                        departmentBox,
                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                                                        105,
                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                                                                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                                                .addGroup(
                                                                                                                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                                                                                        originalPriceText,
                                                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                                                                                        145,
                                                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                                                                                        itemNameText,
                                                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                                                                                        145,
                                                                                                                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                                                                                .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                                                                        javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                                                                                                                                        59,
                                                                                                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                                                                                        calculateButton)))))
                                                                .addGap(0, 33,
                                                                        33))))
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(228, 228, 228)
                                .addComponent(exitButton)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout
                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                                .addGroup(
                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        departmentBox,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                                .addGroup(
                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        itemNameText,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                                .addGroup(
                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        originalPriceText,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                                .addGroup(
                                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        percentDiscountedText,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel3))
                                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                                .addComponent(salesPriceLabel)
                                .addPreferredGap(
                                        javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                                        44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(exitButton).addGap(26, 26, 26))
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(140, 140, 140)
                                .addComponent(calculateButton,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        87,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addContainerGap()));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int number1 = 0, number2 = 0;
        try (
            int = Integer.parseInt(
            this.originalPriceText.getText());
        catch (Excemption e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Price Amount", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        try (
            int = Integer.parseInt(
            this.percentDiscountedText.getText());
        catch (Excemption e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Discount Amount", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        int answer = number1 / number2;
        this.salesPriceLabel.setText("Discounted Sales Price: " / answer);
    }

    private void departmentBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);
        close();

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed"
        // desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase
         * /tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                    .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RetailCalcForm.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RetailCalcForm.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RetailCalcForm.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RetailCalcForm.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // </editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RetailCalcForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton calculateButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField itemNameText;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField originalPriceText;
    private javax.swing.JTextField percentDiscountedText;
    private javax.swing.JLabel salesPriceLabel;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.com. Please post any and all error messages if you are asking us to help you with them. Also, please post *formatted* code. Yours is all left-justified making it hard to read and harder to understand. If you make your code easier to read, you'll likely get better and quicker help. Much luck.

Comment: You might also want to read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for posting guidelines.

Comment: Cross-posted: [java-forums](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/60471-jframe-gui-retail-calculator-will-not-calculate-i-need-help-figuring-out.html)

Comment: NetBeans has nothing to do with your problem!

Comment: You haven't posted formatted code yet.

Answer (score 3):

this is a try catch block (you forget to close the try block with a `}`

```
try {
    number1  = Integer.parseInt(this.percentDiscountedText.getText());
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Discount Amount", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
```

And it's **Exception** not **Excemption**

---

You need a `+` not a `/` to concat string with variables:

```
this.salesPriceLabel.setText("Discounted Sales Price: " +  answer);
```

---

to create an integer you need a name.

```
int = Integer.parseInt("1"); ---> int name = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

But in your case you don't have to create a new int, I suppose you have to use `number1` and `number2`.

---

I don't know whats wrong with this line. First I think you must replace `Cool` with a parenthesis

```
.addGap(28, 28, 2Cool  ---> .addGap(28, 28, 2)
```

but then the calculator is not working any more (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Following is not met: min<=pref<=max`).
Solution for me was to remove this line.

Answer (score 2):

One thing, try/catch blocks use curly braces like all other blocks, not parenthesis.  You have

```
try (
   // some code ...
) catch (Exception e) {
   // catch code here
}
```

when it should be

```
try {
   // some code ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   // catch code here
}
```

But more importantly is your coding style needs to be corrected. You appear to be adding a lot of code to the screen, ignoring all errors until you've typed the whole thing, and that's a recipe for disaster. You need to correct every compilation error after every line or two of code you've added. Else you'll have nothing but a rat's nest of errors that are well nigh uncorrectable.

Comment: OK, replacing the parenthesis helped with some of the errors, Thank you. I also changed the / in my variable string to a +. The problem now is that the calculator says my numbers entered are invalid. the only errors I can still see are found with these lines: int  = Integer.parseInt(. The message says: ';' expected not a statement. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @John: please edit your original post, show the new problem and the newly updated code that's *well formatted*, and show the actual error message(s).

Comment: @JohnEverettJr. or read my answer, there I explain you why this line is wrong

Answer (score 2):

use [JFormattedTextField / JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with [Number Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#format) instead of parsing number from String

Answer (score 1):

You are writing -

```
int=Integer.parseint(this.originalPriceText.getText());
```

which is wrong ! it should be -

```
number1=Integer.parseint(this.originalPriceText.getText());
```

Also, try block is wrapped inside curly braces -

```
try{
    // code goes here
}
catch(Exception ex){
    // code goes here
}
```

Again you are describing the `Exception` to be `Excemption`.

Correcting all these, your method should look like something like below -

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int number1 = 0, number2 = 0;
    try{
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(this.originalPriceText.getText());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Price Amount", "Error", 
                                           JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    try {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(this.percentDiscountedText.getText());
    }
    catch (Excemption e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Discount Amount", "Error", 
                                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    int answer = number1 / number2;
    this.salesPriceLabel.setText("Discounted Sales Price: " / answer);
}
```

You should take a quick tour of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) tutorial.